# SDL_image.h not working, #include "sdl.h" : No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, codeblocks, sdl-2

I am trying to include `<SDL2/SDL_image.h>` in codeblocks but I am unable to

In main.c:
`#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>`

In SDL_image.h:
line 27:`fatal error: SDL.h: no such file or directory`
line 27: `#include "SDL.h"`

These are the search directories in the compiler tab
C:\mingwdevlibs\SDL2-2.0.10\i686-w64-mingw32\include
C:\mingwdevlibs\SDL2_image\i686-w64-mingw32\include

These are the search directories in the linker tab
C:\mingwdevlibs\SDL2-2.0.10\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
C:\mingwdevlibs\SDL2_image\i686-w64-mingw32\lib

These are the linker settings
-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

Comment: Doesn't the error speak for itself? `SDL2/` should be in the include path list, but it isn't.

Comment: Yep I didn't set the path properly. Now the program is working.